# Two level object to given format

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have two level nested object. I need to convert it to array.

```js
var data = {
"6-7":
{
  "0": "06:00",
  "1": "06:10",
  "2": "06:20",
  "3": "06:30",
  "4": "06:40",
  "5": "06:50",
  "6": null,
  "7": null,
  "8": null,
  "9": null,
  "10": null,
  "11": null,
  "12": null,
  "13": null,
  "14": null
},
"7-8": 
{
  "0": "07:00",
  "1": "07:04",
  "2": "07:08",
  "3": "07:12",
  "4": "07:16",
  "5": "07:20",
  "6": "07:24",
  "7": "07:28",
  "8": "07:32",
  "9": "07:36",
  "10": "07:40",
  "11": "07:44",
  "12": "07:48",
  "13": "07:52",
  "14": "07:56"
}
}
```

I tried `Object.values(obj).map(elem => elem)`

it converted to array but still i can't convert it right.
I need to convert it like `[["06:00","06:10",...],[07:00,07:04,...]]`

Thanks for any kind of help.

Edit : data is always same shape not going deeper

Comment: The input data either is already an array, but you've missed typed it out, or it's invalid. Please may you make sure?

Comment: Edited question data is nested object.

Comment: The "edited" question is missing a closing curly braces `}` at the end. One is able to use the snippet to actually **`Run the code snippet`**.

Answer (score 0):

You want just the values of the values, so its as simple as:

```
const result = Object.values(data).map( v => Object.values(v) );
```

If you need to filter out the `null`s then its a tiny bit extra

```
const result = Object.values(data).map( v => Object.values(v).filter(x => x != null) );
```

Live example of the latter

```js
var data={"6-7":{0:"06:00",1:"06:10",2:"06:20",3:"06:30",4:"06:40",5:"06:50",6:null,7:null,8:null,9:null,10:null,11:null,12:null,13:null,14:null},"7-8":{0:"07:00",1:"07:04",2:"07:08",3:"07:12",4:"07:16",5:"07:20",6:"07:24",7:"07:28",8:"07:32",9:"07:36",10:"07:40",11:"07:44",12:"07:48",13:"07:52",14:"07:56"}};

const result = Object.values(data).map( v => Object.values(v).filter(x => x != null) );
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var data = {
"6-7":
{
  "0": "06:00",
  "1": "06:10",
  "2": "06:20",
  "3": "06:30",
  "4": "06:40",
  "5": "06:50",
  "6": null,
  "7": null,
  "8": null,
  "9": null,
  "10": null,
  "11": null,
  "12": null,
  "13": null,
  "14": null
},
"7-8": 
{
  "0": "07:00",
  "1": "07:04",
  "2": "07:08",
  "3": "07:12",
  "4": "07:16",
  "5": "07:20",
  "6": "07:24",
  "7": "07:28",
  "8": "07:32",
  "9": "07:36",
  "10": "07:40",
  "11": "07:44",
  "12": "07:48",
  "13": "07:52",
  "14": "07:56"
}
}

const array = Object.values(data).map(Object.values)

console.log(array);
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is one possible way to achieve the target.

**Code Snippet**

```js
// recursive method to convert object to array
const myConv = obj => (
  Object.entries(obj).flatMap(          // iterate over key-value pairs
    ([k, v]) => (
        v
        ? typeof v === 'object'     // if nested value is object
          ? [myConv(v)]             // nested-array & make the recursive call
          : v                       // else, simply return the value as-is
        : null                      // if value is null, return null
      )
  ).filter(Boolean)                 // filter to remove falsy values
);

const data = {
  "6-7": {
    "0": "06:00",
    "1": "06:10",
    "2": "06:20",
    "3": "06:30",
    "4": "06:40",
    "5": "06:50",
    "6": null,
    "7": null,
    "8": null,
    "9": null,
    "10": null,
    "11": null,
    "12": null,
    "13": null,
    "14": null
  },
  "7-8": {
    "0": "07:00",
    "1": "07:04",
    "2": "07:08",
    "3": "07:12",
    "4": "07:16",
    "5": "07:20",
    "6": "07:24",
    "7": "07:28",
    "8": "07:32",
    "9": "07:36",
    "10": "07:40",
    "11": "07:44",
    "12": "07:48",
    "13": "07:52",
    "14": "07:56"
  }
};

console.log(myConv(data));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0 }
```

**Explanation**

Inline comments added in the snippet above.